# Probability of Getting a 3 on a die on the 2nd throw knowing that 3 only appears on an even throw

Tags: probability

The question in the title (A die is repeatedly thrown until a 3 appears. Knowing that 3 only appears on an even roll, what is the probability that a 3 appears on the 2nd roll?) was a question in an exam.

Intuitively, I thought that it is only $1/6$ because it is already impossible to get the $3$ on the 1st roll, so it is just equal to the probability that we get a 3 when we roll the die the 2nd time, which is $1/6$ (Another way to see it is that this case is equivalent to a case where we are throwing the die repeatedly to get a 3 while denoting the rank of each throw as $({2,4,6,...})$instead of $({1,2,3,...})$ and then asking what the probability of getting a $3$ at rank $2$ is, which is only $1/6$).

However, after the exam, I thought of just applying the conditional probability formula and got a completely different answer (which was the right one). The probability of getting 3 at the 2nd throw and at an even roll is nothing bu the probability of getting $3$ on the 2nd roll, which is $5/36,$ and the probability of getting 3 at an even number (calculated by geometric series) is $5/11,$ so dividing these numbers gives us the final (correct) answer of $11/36.$ Any idea where my logic was flawed to give a wrong answer?

Comment: Rather than "3 only appears on an even throw", it might be easier to think of it as "on odd rolls, a 3 cannot appear".  The condition is a restriction on odd rolls, not on even ones.

Comment: Wall of text, separate your ideas into paragraphs.  Don't make important points in parentheticals, those are for tiny clarifications and meta.  Fix the run on sentences.  Don't make your question a pain to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the following two questions and probabilities:

When you keep throwing dice until you get a 3, and knowing that you end up stopping after an even number of throws, what is the probability that you got the 3 that ended this process on the second throw?

When you keep throwing dice until you get a 3, what is the probability of getting a 3 on the second throw, given that the first throw is not a three?

In the second case the probability is clearly just $\frac{1}{6}$. This is how you thought about the problem initially.

But in the second case you know something more: You know that you stopped after an even number of throws. Knowing this will lower the probability of having gone beyond the second throw, since otherwise you could have thrown a 3 in the third throw. Similarly, the probability of having gone beyond the fourt throw gets lowered as that opens the door for throwing a 3 on the fifth throw, etc. Hence, the probability of having ended the process at the second throw gets increased. Thus, the probability asked about in case 1 is higher than in case 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ count the rolls until we obtain the first 3.   The answers you obtained are actually:

(1) $\mathsf P(R=2\mid R\neq 1) = 1/6$

(2) $\mathsf P(R=2\mid R\in 2\Bbb N) = \dfrac{5/36}{5/11}=\dfrac{11}{36}$

Thus the first answer does not exclude the possibility of obtaining a three on odd rolls after the first should the favoured event fail to happen, which we are informed is *somehow* prohibited.   The second answer correctly evaluates the probability under the required condition.

> Any idea where my logic was flawed to give a wrong answer?

You assumed that on an even roll, the probability for obtaining a three would remain $1/6$ even when you know the event can only happen on an even roll.

However, knowledge that a result of three will occur on some even roll, and is prohibited on all odd rolls, should increase the expectation for obtaining it on any particular even roll.

Comment: Thanks everyone,especially Graham and @Bram28 :D I get it now

Comment: @LameGrass Welcome at Math.SE. If an anwer makes you say "I get it now" then it is a good custom to *accept* that answer.

Comment: @drhab Didn't see that option! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a 5 sided dice, with {1, 2, 4, 5, 6} and a 6 sided dice with {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

Which dice do you throw on the 2nd turn?  What is the probability of getting a 3 when that dice is thrown? Do the results of other turns affect that probability?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two questions.

The answer to the question in which 3 on 2nd roll is $\frac 5{36}$

And answer of getting 3 on even roll is  $\frac 5{11}$